# Is it possible to route request from one domain to different domain in aws api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-eks, amazon-route53

I have API gateway configured in aws. But I want to route the requests from

api.xyz.com/test/create  -> test.xyz.com and authentication need to happen in the API gateway if it's successful then route the request to test.xyz.com .

I have eks configured in the cluster with elb ingress controller, when the requests are routed to test.xyz.com DNS resolution needs to happen within the VPC.

How I can achieve this

Answer (score 1):

You have to create VPC link and NLB target if you want to use api gateway to call private resources.

For more information see:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/understanding-vpc-links-in-amazon-api-gateway-private-integrations/